# Undefined offset error, but offset is not undefined

Tags: php, arrays, offset

I'm getting:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

in my code, however I can print_r the element I am trying to get and its clearly defined.

```
function get_members($entries_found) {
   $members = $entries_found[0]['member'];
   ...
}
```

If I print_r($members) I get the expected output, however I'm still getting the Notice.

Any clues?

Comment: Do the line numbers match for the Notice. It could be elsewhere in your code. The `print_r` output may be helpful.

Comment: Try var_dumping it to make sure the 0 is an int and not '0'

Comment: The line numbers match with the error message. It is definitely the $members = ... line that's throwing the error. I've commented it out to confirm this.

The print_r outputs the array that I am expecting. I cannot paste it here as it contains sensitive information.

The 0 is definitely an int and not a '0'.

Comment: Please provide the array code and/or function code, to have a better look for other users, so as to help in the debugging process.

Comment: PHP would not lie to you when it gives you that notice. You must overlook something, probably do a `print_r($entries_found)` and especially if you actually want to write good code, check the existence of an index before you obtain a value from it.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
var_dump($entries_found);
```

To check that the array does indeed have an offset of zero.  Other things you can try would be reseting the array pointer

```
reset($entries_found);
```

of checking if it's set first

```
if (isset($entries_found[0]['member'])) // do things
```

If all else fails you could just supress the notice with

```
$members = @$entries_found[0]['member'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what happens with your `$entries_found` before accessing it from `get_members`

But i had the same problem. `print_r` and `var_dump` showed me, that the index exists but when i tried to access it i got the `offset error`

In my case i decoded a json string with `json_decode` without setting the `assoc` flag.

```
// Not working
$assocArray = json_decode('{"207":"sdf","210":"sdf"}');
echo $assocArray[207];


// working witht the assoc flag set
$assocArray = json_decode('{"207":"sdf","210":"sdf"}', true);
echo $assocArray[207];
```

Got my solution from here: [Undefined offset while accessing array element which exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090328/undefined-offset-while-accessing-array-element-which-exists)