# Undefined offset while accessing array element which exists

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, element, undefined

I have an array and PHP and when I print it out I can see the values I need to access, but when I try accessing them by their key I am getting a PHP Notice. I printed the array with [print_r](http://php.net/print_r):

```
Array
(
    [207] => sdf
    [210] => sdf
)
```

When I try to access the array using the index I get an undefined offset notice. Here is my code:

```
print_r($output); 
echo $output[207];   // Undefined Offset
echo $output["207"]; // Undefined Offset
```

The `$output` array is the result of a call to [array_diff_key](http://php.net/array_diff_key) and is input originally as JSON through an HTTP POST request.

[array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys) gives me the following:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 207
   [1] => 210
)
```

---

In response to the comments:

`var_dump(key($output));` outputs:

> ```
>    string(3) "207"
> ```

`var_dump(isset($output[key($output)]));` outputs:

> ```
>    bool(false)
> ```

Comment: Try `var_dump(key($output))` and tell us what you get.

Comment: Need more information.  What context?  Is this in a server-side script?

Comment: @deceze: This is the output `string '207' (length=3)`

Comment: @deceze: Yes, I am using a lot of arrays in the code. But this simple one is driving me nuts. :-)

Comment: @ascii-lime: Nothing special. As usual PHP :-). Yes, pretty confusing.

Comment: @ascii-lime: Strange... `boolean false`

Comment: @ascii-lime: Yes, of course :-)

Comment: @ascii-lime: PHP Version 5.3.10. Not using serialization.

Comment: @ascii-lime: I get this output array from `array_diff_key` function, if it helps.

Comment: Can you post more code — preferably from the actual decoding from JSON onwards; as stated in existing answers, this is likely caused by the PHP bug in casting objects to arrays (which the PHP devs refuse to admit as a bug and have canonized as "expected behavior" in the docs); now the question is where does this happen and how to work around it.

Comment: You can also try `var_dump(array_key_exists($output[key($output)]));`  and `echo bin2hex(key($output));`  to complete all tests :-)

Comment: What does `var_dump($output);` produce? I can't reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 25):

See this section on converting an object to an array in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting):

> The keys are the member variable names, with a few notable exceptions: ***integer properties are unaccessible***; private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name.

When converting to an array from an object in PHP, integer array keys are stored internally as strings. When you access array elements in PHP or use an array normally, keys that contain valid integers will be converted to integers automatically.  An integer stored internally as a string is an inaccessible key.

Note the difference:

```
$x = (array)json_decode('{"207":"test"}');
var_dump(key($x));  // string(3) "207"

var_dump($x);
// array(1) {
//   ["207"]=>
//   string(4) "test"
// }


$y['207'] = 'test';
var_dump(key($y));  // int(207)

var_dump($y);
// array(1) {
//   [207]=>
//   string(4) "test"
// }
```

[print_r](http://php.net/print_r) on both those arrays gives identical output, but with [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump) you can see the differences.

Here is some code that reproduces your exact problem:

```
$output = (array)json_decode('{"207":"sdf","210":"sdf"}');

print_r($output);
echo $output[207];
echo $output["207"];
```

And the simple fix is to pass in `true` to [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) for the optional `assoc` argument, to specify that you want an array not an object:

```
$output = json_decode('{"207":"sdf","210":"sdf"}', true);

print_r($output);
echo $output[207];
echo $output["207"];
```

Comment: The original array is decoded from JSON POST. But the array I have problem with, is the result of array_diff_key call.

Comment: @KevinRave Yes, because the input array to the call has the same problem. Try accessing `$arr[207]` in whatever array you are passing in as the first argument to `array_diff_key` and you'll see the exact same issue. You need to fix the source of the problem which will be from casting an object to an array at some point using something like: `$array = (array)$obj;`

Comment: I tried changing the original array. And tried a few other things. Nothing worked. I ended up getting the key/value through foreach looping. But this seems to be a bug. :-)

Comment: @KevinRave Can you verify that you have the same problem with your original array?

Comment: @KevinRave:  `$first = (array)json_decode('{"207":"sdf","210":"sdf"}',true); $output = array_diff($first, array());print_r($output);echo $output[207];echo $output["207"];` array_diff is not a problem, the solution is still valid. Try to remove the true in previous code you have your bug.

Comment: I have included the `json_decode(..., true)` (of which I knew of from the start) in my answer. Normally I don't consider it correct to write an answer as an enhanced answer of someone else, and this is the reason why I hadn't done it before, but now I realized that the bounty is yours, and you cannot give it to yourself, and you already got 9 votes, so in this case I don't see a reason not to complete my answer - unless you have a good counter-argument, of course.

Comment: thank you for the bounty, ascii-lime! It's funny that @KevinRave hasn't accepted neither your answer nor mine yet, although I believe that both our answers are correct and useful. I don't think that it's possible that there is no conversion from object to array in his code. `array_diff_key()` doesn't accept object arguments, for one.

Answer (score 22):

The problem arises when [casting](http://it.php.net/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) to `array` an object that has string keys that are valid integers.

If you have this object:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["207"]=>
  string(3) "sdf"
  ["210"]=>
  string(3) "sdf"
}
```

and you cast it with

```
$array = (array)$object
```

you get this array

```
array(2) {
  ["207"]=>
  string(3) "sdf"
  ["210"]=>
  string(3) "sdf"
}
```

which has keys that can only be accessed by looping through them, since a direct access like `$array["207"]` will always be [converted](http://it.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func) to `$array[207]`, which does not exist.

Since you are getting an object like the one above from `json_decode()` applied to a string like

```
$json = '{"207":"sdf", "210":"sdf"}'
```

The best solution would be to avoid numeric keys in the first place. These are probably better modelled as numeric properties of an array of objects:

```
$json = '[{"numAttr":207, "strAttr":"sdf"}, {"numAttr":210, "strAttr":"sdf"}]'
```

This data structure has several advantages over the present one:

1. it better reflects the original data, as a collection of objects
   which have a numeric property
2. it is readily extensible with other properties
3. it is more portable across different systems
   (as you see, your current data structure is causing issues in PHP, but if you
   should happen to use another language you may easily encounter
   similar issues).

If a property → object map is needed, it can be quickly obtained, e.g., like this:

```
function getNumAttr($obj) { return $obj->numAttr; } // for backward compatibility
$arr = json_decode($json); // where $json = '[{"numAttr":...
$map = array_combine(array_map('getNumAttr', $arr), $arr);
```

The other solution would be to do as ascii-lime suggested: force [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to output associative arrays instead of objects, by setting its second parameter to `true`:

```
$map = json_decode($json, true);
```

For your input data this produces directly

```
array(2) {
  [207]=>
  string(3) "sdf"
  [210]=>
  string(3) "sdf"
}
```

Note that the keys of the array are now integers instead of strings.

I would consider changing the JSON data structure a much cleaner solution, though, although I understand that it might not be possible to do so.

Comment: It's funny being upvoted and then un-upvoted after some time. In case something wrong has been discovered in my answer, I would be curious to know what it is

Answer (score 1):

I've just found [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43614) which causes array elements to be inaccessible sometimes in PHP when the array is created by a call to [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize).

Create a test PHP file containing (or run from the command line) the following script:

```
<?php 

$a = unserialize('a:2:{s:2:"10";i:1;s:2:"01";i:2;}'); 

print $a['10']."\n";

$a['10'] = 3; 
$a['01'] = 4; 

print_r($a);

foreach ($a as $k => $v) 
{ 
  print 'KEY: '; 
  var_dump($k); 
  print 'VAL: '; 
  var_dump($v); 
  print "\n"; 
}
```

If you get errors you have a version of PHP with this bug in it and I recommend upgrading to PHP 5.3

Comment: i am using php 5.6 stucked in same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var_dump($output);
foreach ($output as $key => val) {
    var_dump($key);
    var_dump($val);
}
```

to learn more on what is happening.

What exact line/statement is throwing you a warning?

Answer (score 0):

How did you print the array?  I would suggest `print_r($arrayName);`

Next, you can print individual elements like: `echo $arrayName[0];`

Comment: As you can see, I used `print_r`. And accessing it by [0] is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try use my approach:

```
class ObjectToArray {
    public static function convert( $object ) {
        if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) ) {
            return $object;
        }

        if( is_object( $object ) ) {
           $object = get_object_vars( $object );
        }

        return array_map( 'ObjectToArray::convert', $object );
    }
}

$aNewArray = ObjectToArray::convert($oYourObject);
```

Answer (score -2):

Just put error_reporting(0); in you method or at start of file. It will solved your issue.