# Faulty notice undefined index

Tags: php, notice, undefined-index

I'm getting an undefined index notice, though the index is defined. PHP version is 5.6

Code:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$array = explode('?', $url);

var_dump($array);

echo "<br>".$array[0]."<br>";
echo "this is value 1:".$array[1]."<br>"; //line 9
```

Output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "/customers" [1]=> string(9) "name=test" }
/customers
this is value 1:name=test
```

This all makes sense, but I also get this notice:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in
>   /var/source/united/magebo/api/api.php on line 9

Any idea where this notice is coming from?

I tried setting the url hard coded to the same value, the notice disappears. I found allot of questions about this issue but in my case the index *IS* defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: This is not a duplicate since my index is defined...

Comment: provide some example , like when this notice comes and when not ? I think you put all code in one page. and you have not checked by isset function.

Comment: very strange!! use foreach loop and print value. check you got one value or both. OR use array_values($array);

Comment: i tried ur Code and is it working 100% without errors. there musst be another issue. what is the Code infront or after ur script ?

Comment: No code before or after. What is your php version? Found kind of a duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090328/undefined-offset-while-accessing-array-element-which-exists

Comment: What is the exact output of: `highlight_string(print_r($array, TRUE));`?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => /customers
    [1] => name=test
)

I think this is just a bug...